# Is 気象庁 used only for JMA or any general meteorological observatory?

Tags: meaning

Everywhere I tried searching 気象庁 on the internet, I found that it is only associated with JMA. But my 先生 firmly argues that 気象庁 does not only mean JMA but general meteorological observatory/agency. I found 気象台 for general observatory but my sensei is adamant so I wanted to hear it from natives. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

庁 is a kanji for *national* agencies, so you cannot use 庁 for observatories in general. For example, a weather station run by a university or a private company is definitely not 庁, although it may be called a 気象台 or 気象観測所. World Meteorological Organization run by the UN is not 気象庁, either. Here is the current list of Japanese 庁: [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/庁](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%81)

庁 itself can be used for other countries' national agencies similar to Japanese 庁. For example there is [大韓民国気象庁](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E9%9F%93%E6%B0%91%E5%9B%BD%E6%B0%97%E8%B1%A1%E5%BA%81) in Korea. Still, not all national organizations in charge of weather are run in the form similar to Japanese 庁, so 庁 is not a suitable generic term for them. For example, Italian Meteorological Service is a sub-unit of Italian army, so it's not a 庁.

Japanese Wikipedia has a list of government-run meteorological offices: [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/気象機関の一覧](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B0%97%E8%B1%A1%E6%A9%9F%E9%96%A2%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7) Judging from this and some articles linked from this, there is no simple "generic term" for JMA-like organizations in various countries. You have to say 気象機関, 気象に関する国家機関, etc.

Comment: それはいい説明でしたね！どうもありがとうnarutoさん！